# ng-click not firing on modal panel angularjs v 1.3.17

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I must be missing something here. I have a module like below:

```
    (function (app) {
    'use strict';

    app.controller('modalCtrl', modalCtrl);

    modalCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$modalInstance'];

    function modalCtrl($scope, $modalInstance) {


        $scope.closeModal = closeModal;

        function closeModal() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss();
        }
    }

})(angular.module('mainModule'));
```

I call the closeModal function from this vew:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Heading!
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Some message.
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="closeModal()">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modal opens as expected, however it cannot be closed by clicking ok button. The code opening modal is below:

```
function openDialog() {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        controller: 'modalCtrl',
        scope: $scope
    }).result.then(function ($scope) {
       //some code here
    }, function () {

    });
}
```

EDIT:
openDialog function is in different controller than closeModal. Nothing seem to work below. To me it appears as if ng-click on closeModal doesn't find its controller to invoke closeModal, however there is no error thrown for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the modal like this:

```
function openDialog() {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        controller: 'modalCtrl',
        scope: this.$new()
    }).result.then(function ($scope) {
       //some code here
    }, function () {

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a instance of your modal first

```
function openDialog() {
    $scope.modal = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        controller: 'modalCtrl',
        scope: $scope
    }).result.then(function ($scope) {
       //some code here
    }, function () {

    });
}
 function closeModal() {
            $scope.modal.dismiss();//or close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

remove scope:$scope from openDialg function

```
function openDialog() {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        controller: 'modalCtrl'
    }).result.then(function ($scope) {
       //some code here
    }, function () {

    });
}
```